# How to recognize strings in php?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

When I type:

```
<?php
  $temp="1234";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write({$temp});</script>";
?>
```

I get 1234 on the screen.

But when I replace `$temp="1234"` with `$temp="alfa"` I get nothing on the screen.

What's the problem ? Where am I wrong ? "1234" and "alfa" are both strings

Comment: Look at the resulting Javascript. You need to use quotes around the string. `1234` just happens to be interpreted as a number

Comment: Maybe you need to add quotes around it in your `document.write` call?

Comment: change `.write({$temp})` to `.write(\"{$temp}\")`

Comment: Is there some reason that `echo $temp;` just isn't enough?

Answer (score 2):

`alert(1234)` is valid javascript, and will simply pop up the integer 1234 on your screen.
`alert(alfa)` is attempting to pop up the contents of a variable named `alfa` on your screen, which doesn't exist.

If you're insert data from PHP into a Javascript context, you MUST use json_encode() to ensure that you're producing VALID javascript. e.g.

```
$temp = 'alfa';
$json=  json_encode($temp);
echo '<script>.... {$json}...</script>';
```

that will produce `alert('alfa')` and work as expected.

Comment: json works great! Thanks! It's exactly what I need! I didn't know about this method!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't enclosing the text in the double-quote character '"' which denotes a string.

`document.write(1234)` works because `1234` is a valid value in JavaScript (an integer), whereas `alfa` is a symbol name, it should be `"alfa"`.